# How to stop NetworkActivityIndicator, after the data loading process

Tags: ios, viewwillappear

I'm loading data into  a collectionview from a json feed. I have set a network activity indicator in my viewWillappear method.it works fine. But I want to stop it when data loading is finished.How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code which reloads your UICollectionView, you can just switch the network activity indicator off, e.g.

```
[collectionView reloadData];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```